# lstrip gets rid of letter

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

With Python 2.7, I ran into the following problem: I have urls that I would like to clean, in particular I'd like to get rid of "http://".

This works:

```
>>> url = 'http://www.party.com'
>>> url.lstrip('http://')
'www.party.com'
```

But why does this not work?

```
>>> url = 'http://party.com'
>>> url.lstrip('http://')
'arty.com'
```

It gets rid of 'p' from 'party'.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Think the argument of `lstrip` as characters, not a string.

[`url.lstrip('http://')`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.lstrip) removes all leading `h`, `t`, `:`, `/` from `url`.

Use [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.replace) instead:

```
>>> url = 'http://party.com'
>>> url.replace('http://', '', 1)
'party.com'
```

If what you really want is get hostname from the url, you can also use [`urlparse.urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse#urlparse.urlparse):

```
>>> urlparse.urlparse('http://party.com').netloc
'party.com'
>>> urlparse.urlparse('http://party.com/path/to/some-resource').netloc
'party.com'
```