# Python strip() function - remove characters before/after string

Tags: python, arrays, string, strip

I am trying to remove everything in the following array except for the two numbers and the `,` in between.

This is the array:
`[array([[ 1948.97753906,  1058.23937988]], dtype=float32)]`

This array is always changing in size (can have 1 pair of numbers or 6 pairs etc) and being filled with different numbers, however, the format always remains the same.

I currently have the below code, however, I think this is only working when there is one pair of numbers in the array??

```
final = str(self.lostfeatures).strip('[array([[ ').strip(']], dtype=float32)')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [lstrip gets rid of letter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425813/lstrip-gets-rid-of-letter)

Comment: you always want 1 pair of numbers? even array contains 6 pairs? if so which pair do you want?

Comment: It looks as if your array is a numpy array? Why use string manipulation to extract stuff from it? Why not simply get the numbers out of the array?

Comment: This souns like an [X Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) and what you really want is something like @JonClements answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if that is really just a prefix/suffix, use `replace`:

```
final = str(self.lostfeatures).replace('[array([[','').replace(']], dtype=float32)', '')
```

You can do something similar with regex:

```
numbers = re.findall('(?P<number>\d+\.\d+)', str(self.lostfeatures))
```

which will also give you an array of the numbers themselves (so it's trivial to cast to float from there).

However... if you are doing str(lostfeatures), the original must already be in an array. Why are you even casting to string? You should be able to extract the numerical array directly like this:

```
lostfeatures[0][0]
```

(you appear to have two levels of indirection... `lostfeatures[0]` = `array([[ 1948.97753906, 1058.23937988]]`, then `lostfeatures[0][0]` == `[1948.97753906, 1058.23937988]`). It's not clear exactly what your data structure looks like, but that would be by far the fastest.

Comment: Thanks Corley, I used your final suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a punt that you've got a 2D numpy array (`self.features`) of (coordinate pairs?) and you want to format each row (position?), eg:

```
for pair in self.features: 
    print '{0}, {1}'.format(*pair)
```

Answer (score 0):

As in your example. I think that answers your question.

```
>>> x = "[array([[ 1948.97753906, 1058.23937988]], dtype=float32)]"
>>> print x.split("[[")[1].split("]]")[0].replace(",","")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always the same, that is it always starts with `"[array([["` and always ends with `"]], dtype=float32)"` you should use a slice instead.

```
final = str(self.lostfeatures)[len('[array([[ '):-len(']], dtype=float32)')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably recommend a regex for this use case

```
import re

ptrn = re.compile(r'((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?, ?)+(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?))'

x = "[array([[ 1948.97753906, 1058.23937988]], dtype=float32)]"
print ptrn.search(x).group(1)
```